# cygwin package binaries are missing after installation

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, package-management

I've been using the cygwin and its package manager for months now without a problem.

Today I tried to install "curl"+ "jq" (Bin) and even though it did not throw an error and is showing as "installed", the binaries are missing.

Verifying package is listed as installed:
[image: curl installed]

Changing the view to "picked":
[image: curl and jq picked]

Log output:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Users/MYUSER/Downloads/setup-x86_64.exe -BM
Starting cygwin install, version 2.893
User has NO backup/restore rights
Current Directory: C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop
Could not open Service control manager
root: C:\cygwin64 user
Selected local directory: C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop
net: Proxy
site: ftp://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/
solving: 0 tasks, update: yes, use test packages: no
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
solving: 0 tasks, update: no, use test packages: no
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_000_autorebase.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db.sh"
Ending cygwin install
```

I tried to to rebaseall with:

```
$ /usr/bin/rebase-trigger full
```

The binaries are downloaded but wont get copied to their destination.
I double checked "Install from internet" is selected.

Reinstalling the packages:

```
<snip>
solving: 0 tasks, update: no, use test packages: no
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
solving: 2 tasks, update: no, use test packages: no
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
Augmented Transaction List:
   0   erase                                            curl            7.59.0-1
   1 install                                            curl            7.59.0-1
   2   erase                                              jq               1.5-3
   3 install                                              jq               1.5-3
Uninstalling curl
Uninstalling jq
Extracting from file://C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.fau.de%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/curl/curl-7.59.0-1.tar.xz
Extracting from file://C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.fau.de%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/jq/jq-1.5-3.tar.xz
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_000_autorebase.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db.sh"
note: Installation Complete
Ending cygwin install
```

Still no curl or jq in PATH.
Maybe someone has an idea to fix this.

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -v -c curl` ?

Comment: pretty much empty: $ cygcheck -v -c curl

Cygwin Package Information
Last downloaded files to: C:\Users\MYUSER\cygwinpgks
Last downloaded files from: http://ftp.fau.de/cygwin/

Package              Version        Status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! The installation path was custom (in my user directory), the cygwin setup.exe uses C:\cygwin64 per default (?) and installed the binaries there.
Changing the root dir for cygwin fixed the issue.

Comment: There are reasons for "C:\cygwin64" default and not to use the user directory

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately I had to choose another directory.